# How to pull out object within array to new array of object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-structures

**Given:**

```
[{
  "date": "2020-12-23",
  "info": [{
      "filled": 4,
    },
    {
      "filled": 10,
    },
  ]
}, {
  "date": "2020-12-30",
  "info": [{
    "filled": 6,
  }]
}]
```

**Desired Result**

```
[
  {
    "filled": 4,
    "date": "2020-12-23"
  },
  {
    "filled": 10,
    "date": "2020-12-23"
  },
  {
    "filled": 6,
    "date": "2020-12-30"
  }
]
```

How to makes filled value pair with date value?

i can fetch data from GraphQL like this:

```
[{
  "date": "2020-12-23",
  "info": [{
      "filled": 4,
      "date": "2020-12-23",
    },
    {
      "filled": 10,
      "date": "2020-12-23",
    },
  ]
}, {
  "date": "2020-12-30",
  "info": [{
    "filled": 6,
    "date": "2020-12-30",
  }]
}]
```

but still unclear how to pair filled with date in one array of objects, because first get fetch data by date then show info, within info thereis date data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following,

```js
data = [{
  "date": "2020-12-23",
  "info": [{
      "filled": 4,
      "date": "2020-12-23",
    },
    {
      "filled": 10,
      "date": "2020-12-23",
    },
  ]
}, {
  "date": "2020-12-30",
  "info": [{
    "filled": 6,
    "date": "2020-12-30",
  }]
}]

ret = data.map(item => item.info.map(info => info)).flat();
console.log(ret);
```